# Need guidance on mocking data from a wearable device for Android app development with react native

Tags: android, react-native, mocking, wear-os

I am working on react native app that encourages users to stand up and avoid prolonged periods of sitting. The app relies on data from a wearable device to track user activity. However, due to limitations, I am unable to implement the necessary components for the wearable device at the moment.

I'm looking for guidance on how to mock the data received from a wearable device to test and develop the app without the physical device. What are the best practices and tools for simulating wearable device data on an Android app? Are there any libraries or methods that can help me achieve this?

I appreciate any insights, code examples, or resources that can point me in the right direction. Thank you!